# How to return timeframe.period as integer in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I cannot post in public chat although I'm on trial and ready to pay for the subscription (as I understand then I do not need 5 reputation points to post?). Can you please help?

Comment: Are you trying ask a question? What public chat and subscription are you talking about? Please make it clear for anyone who doesn't know what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeframe.multiplier](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_timeframe%7Bdot%7Dmultiplier) instead - it will return integer value.

However note that it would return **1** on 1 minute, 1 day or 1 week charts, so you have to additionally check the scale of the timeframe using the [timeframe.isintraday](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_timeframe%7Bdot%7Disintraday), [timeframe.isdaily](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_timeframe%7Bdot%7Disdaily) etc built-in functions.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I found this out already and used this method to get to what I want. Cheers